# Fastest/easiest way to build a HTML5 mobile app (agile)

Tags: html, mobile, agile

Last time I coded for mobile was with Phonegap 1.0. And I know there's a lot of frameworks to build a mobile app faster.

What I need is a mobile framework light-weight, fast, with all typical mobile UI animations (snackbars, notifications, menus, slides, panels, alerts, modals ...), easily to export to Android & iPhone (I know Phonegap still does that).

Also I'd like a library/framework/SDK to easily do typical MVC things from mobile to server. I don't know if there's open-source solutions or I should pay for one. I mean to create easily the user stuff (login/register, connect with Facebook, connect with Google+ ...), create models easily, and API REST calls to insert/search into those models / database ...

I don't remember what it was, or where I saw, but I remember some SDK that provides these kind of "core" things (user administration, models ...)

Does anyone know anything interesting to start ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend AngularJs in combination with the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) and deploy with Cordova/Phonegap.

Comment: Ionic is one of the frameworks I heard about ... what about the API calls and backend ?  I saw this : http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/backend-data/   do you know any backend service (open source if possible) ?  I'd do it in Yii, but if there is something more "agile" to implement ...  ;-)

Comment: I've seen BaasBox or Amazon SDK ... suggestions ?

Comment: I only have experience with [Parse](https://www.parse.com/). It's owned by facebook.